# Implementing Select List Lookup ViewModel Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, service, viewmodel, automapper

I'm trying to implement a more customisable version of using ViewModel attributes and a Model Enricher to populate viewmodels lists like in this [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3507466/629323) and associated [blog post](http://blog.opo.li/post/ASPNET-MVC-Loading-data-for-select-lists-into-edit-model-using-attributes.aspx).

I would like to be able to specify the method on my select list interface from the Attribute.

Each Select List service I have returns an IEnumerable that I use to make a select list and presently exposes an All interface as the sample does. I can easily use the All method because all interfaces provide that. However I often wish to able to use other methods like the AllTradingCompanies() AllManafacturingCompanies() methods of my select list class to get filtered lists.

It is presently looking like I may have to implement a Custom attribute to map to specific e.g. [AllCompanyList] attributes but that moves me away from the nice generic method that the existing version gives me. I guess I could use it to complement it but then its starting to lose some of the charm. I also am implementing IModelEnrichers which can do custom per view model logic.

Any thoughts on a nice way to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the solution using pairs of Attributes to define a requirement for data on a ViewModel and a provider of data a repository or a service within my domain. See my [follow up question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7768601/629323) asking whether this is a good idea.