# ASP.NET MVC 2 DropDownList not Setting the Selected Value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I am trying to populate the dropdown value with the selected value.
I referred to related articles and I am doing the same. Still Dropdown is not populating with the selected Value. Not sure what I am missing.

**Controller Code:**

```
var RegionId = new[] { 
                new RegionKeyValues { RegionId = 1, RegionValue = "A" }, 
                new RegionKeyValues { RegionId = 2, RegionValue = "B" }, 
                new RegionKeyValues { RegionId = 3, RegionValue = "D" } 
            };
ViewData["RegionId"] = new SelectList(RegionId, "RegionId", "RegionValue", 1);
```

**View Code:**

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("RegionId",
                      (SelectList)ViewData["RegionId"],
                      "-- Select --")%>
```

Comment: I don't think the question is clear. The drop down list doesn't populate the list with the contents of the RegionId list? Or you think that the list is supposed to preselect a value and it is not?

Comment: Dropdown is populating fine with those 3 records. But it is not setting to "A"

Comment: No.. It is not Dupe... There are couple of related... But My Dropdown is not setting to selected value of "A" that is 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is with the fact your property name is RegionId, as well as the ViewData name. Change one and see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try`<%=Html.DropDownList("RegionId", new SelectList((IEnumerable)ViewData["RegionId"], "Value", "Text",1),"-- Select --")`%>

Setting the value in the actual view.

Also in general I would create a strongly typed ViewModel and create properties storing the select list values as an `IEnumerable<SelecListItem>`

Then you can do

```
<%=Html.DropDownListFor(a=>a.RegionId, new SelectList(Model.Regions, "Value", "Text"),"-- Select --")`%>
```

Where RegionId would be the actual value to set to and Model.Regions stores the list of possible regions.

In general I feel a good approach to controllers and lists, viewmodels etc is in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136091/mvc-controller-with-multiple-select-lists/9141989#9141989)

Answer (score 1):

Rita,

Here's my effort on this:

the model:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class RegionKeyValues
    {
        public int RegionId { get; set; }
        public string RegionValue { get; set; }
    }

    public class RegionKeyValuesViewModel
    {
        public int SelectedRegionId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<RegionKeyValues> RegionList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var regionList = new[] { 
        new RegionKeyValues { RegionId = 1, RegionValue = "A" }, 
        new RegionKeyValues { RegionId = 2, RegionValue = "B" }, 
        new RegionKeyValues { RegionId = 3, RegionValue = "D" } 
    };

    var viewModel = new RegionKeyValuesViewModel
    {
        RegionList = regionList, 
        SelectedRegionId = 1 // hardcoded here, but in real-life, from the db
    };

    ViewData.Model = viewModel;

    return View();
}
```

View code (in Razor):

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.RegionKeyValuesViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(a => a.SelectedRegionId, 
    new SelectList(Model.RegionList, "RegionId", "RegionValue", 
        Model.SelectedRegionId), "-- Select --")
```

so basically, I'm passing a strongly typed ViewModel down to the view and setting the selected RegionId in the controller and passing that to Model.SelectedRegionId. In a real app, you'd obviously be getting the viewModel from the db or some other structure.

worth considering as an alternative.